# Create DataFrames based on unique values of a Column using Pandas then export to excel for each DF created

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have a set of data that needs to be filtered and saved in different excel based on unique values in a column. for example, in `SRC` column below, all rows with `AAA` under `SRC` will be in one excel named `AAA.xlsx` and all rows with `BBB` under `SRC` will be in another excel named `BBB.xlsx` and so on.

Appreciate any help and advise!

```
SRC Data1 Data2
AAA  180   122
BBB  168   121
CCC  165   147
DDD  140   156
EEE  152   103
AAA  170   100
CCC  166   112
DDD  116   155
EEE  179   119
```

I managed to create 3 dictionaries but can't figure out how to export all 3 dictionaries to 3 different excel.

```
g = output.groupby("SRC", as_index=False)
d = dict(iter(g))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop and each group write to file:

```
for name, g in output.groupby('SRC'):
    g.to_excel(f'{name}.xlsx', index=False)
```